# How to fill condition for Object in Drools rule template with @{variablePart}?

Tags: templates, conditional-statements, drools, rule

I have a rule template (non-decision table based) with a condition (aka constraint) for an object. This condition should be filled based on the variables/parameters set for this rule template when compiling it via Drools' Object Compiler. The example below shows what I'm trying to do - but sadly this is not compiling. The error messages are not explaining and subsequent null pointer exceptions are the consequence.

```
rule "variable condition"
when
    Person ( @{condition} )
then
    // do something...
end
```

On java side the variable part is then passed to the Drools Object Compiler similar to this:

```
String condition = "id == 42";
String compiledRule = objectDataCompiler.compile(data, ...
```

Or similar to the next example, showing a conditional operator connecting several acceptable values:

```
String condition = "(id == 42) || (id == 52)";
String compiledRule = objectDataCompiler.compile(data, ...
```

Even with the first example for the java-side code the rule template would not compile.

How can one setup a working templated rule for achieving such variable conditions?

Answer (score 1):

The rule template is used to dynamically update rule. The format to define rule is done by creating a Condition and then use the method of the Condition class to define the rule. For example,

```
Rule highValueOrderRule = new Rule();
Condition highValueOrderCondition = new Condition();
highValueOrderCondition.setField("price");
highValueOrderCondition.setOperator(Condition.Operator.GREATER_THAN);
highValueOrderCondition.setValue(5000.0);

// In reality, you would have multiple rules for different types of events. 
// The eventType property would be used to find rules relevant to the event
highValueOrderRule.setEventType(Rule.eventType.ORDER);

highValueOrderRule.setCondition(highValueOrderCondition);
```

Rule template is beautiful explained in this [blog](http://oncodesign.io/2015/08/10/dynamically-create-rules-using-drools--rule-templates/)

Comment: Though offering a thorough explanation the source above goes into a different approach for creating rules. Instead of this programmatic rule creation, I'm having a more verbose laid out DRT file containing the rule and the rule properties (the variables) defined in the beginning. Now the part these variables are to change are certain lines in the conditions of written out rules.

Comment: how to pass multiple rules to applyRuleTemplate() method from the blog?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/claudemamo/dynamic-drools-rules/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ossandme/Program.java) github repository i found while searching for the similar problem on how to use template to define a rule. Worked like a charm for me.